# How to add an uitableview as a subview to ui scrollview in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, swift, subview

I have an `UIScrollView` called **ContentView** in my `ContentViewController`, and an `UITableView` call **TimelineTable** in my `TimelineViewController`.

When i create and add `TimelineViewController` as a subview to **ContentView**, if **TimelineTable** doesn't have any cells, i can scroll the table without problem, if **TimelineTable** has cells, it shows up but when i scroll the table, the app crashes. It gave me **EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1)**

If i present `TimelineViewController`, everything is fine. But i want to know how to add `TimelineViewController` as a subview to my **ContentView**,

One more thing, everything is fine when use **Objective C**, now i use **Swift** and this problem come. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: not sure exactly what content you are trying to display on your scrollview vs your tableview. but having two scrolling objects is kind of a mess. specifically you'll have to deal with scroll and touch events for two different scrolling areas. The reason it works without cells is there's no scrolling mechanism in the tableview. if you want to display content above and below your tableview, consider adding the content into a separate cell instead of putting it into the scrollview. if you have content to the left and right of the tableview, consider a collection view though they're unwieldy.

Comment: well, i try creating a view controller like this


|-view
|--scrollview
|---tableview


and when i present this view controller with cells, it's working fine. so i think the problem maybe because they are in seperated view controllers.

Comment: yea, weird things will happen if you put a tableview inside the scrollview, as a subview. i'm not really sure what might be causing the crash but i think it'll be easier to not layer them together, especially if you're also putting a tableView inside another controller then adding the controller's subview into the scrollview. view hierarchies should be relatively simple.